# Library of Useful (Difficult) SQL scripts

Tags: sql, scripting

Does anyone know where I can find a library of common but difficult (out of the ordinary) SQL script examples. I am talking about those examples you cannot find in the documentation but do need very often to accomplish tasks such as finding duplicates etc.

It would be a big time saver to have something like that handy.

EDIT: Thanks everyone, I think this is turning into a great quick reference. The more descriptive the more effective it would be, so please if you see your way open - please edit and add some descriptions of what one could find. Many thanks to those that have already done so!

Comment: Where are the common sense? How can this be item be "Not Constructive" if it has 130 followers and 53 upvotes. It clearly has great value to many people.

Comment: think it's on the community Wiki so even though closed it is still in use

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You may find [this wiki on LessThanDot](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Category:Microsoft_SQL_Server) useful, for the most part, it is by Denis Gobo, Microsoft SQL MVP.

EDIT:
The wiki includes **100+ SQL Server Programming Hacks**, the list is, I think, too long to include here, however, there is a [comprehensive index](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/SQL_Server_Programming_Hacks_-_100%2B_List).

Also available from the same site: [SQL Server Admin Hacks](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/SQL_Server_Admin_Hacks).

Comment: I wish it had all those scripts for the other major SQL platforms

Answer (score 24):

Here are a few that I find very useful:

- [SQL Server Best Practices](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/bb331794.aspx) - Microsoft SQL Server White Papers and Best Practices
- [vyaskn](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/) - A mixture of articles From DBA to Developer
- [Backup, Integrity Check and Index
  Optimization](http://blog.ola.hallengren.com/blog/_archives/2008/1/1/3440068.html)
- [SQLServerCentral Scripts](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Scripts/) - Scripts for most most DBA tasks and more
- [Script Repository: SQL Server 2005](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/scripts/sql/sql2005/default.mspx?mfr=true) - TechNet Script Center
- [Scripts and Tools for Performance Tuning and Troubleshooting SQL Server 2005](http://sqlcat.com/toolbox/archive/2008/02/21/scripts-and-tools-for-performance-tuning-and-troubleshooting-sql-server-2005.aspx)
- [SQL Server Query Processing Team](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlqueryprocessing/default.aspx) - Hardcore advice from the MS SQL optimisation team
- [Common Solutions for T-SQL Problems](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples)
- [Davide Mauri's Index Scripts](http://www.davidemauri.it/SqlScripts.aspx)

Answer (score 16):

### Some Administration stuff

Glenn Berry: [Five Very Useful Index Selection Queries for SQL Server 2005](http://glennberrysqlperformance.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!45041418ECCAA960!715.entry)

- Find "Missing" Indexes for the entire instance of SQL Server
- Find "Missing" Indexes for a single table
- Examine the current index structure for a single table
- Look at index usage for a single table
- Look for possible bad indexes inside the entire current database
- Drill into your workload (Bonus)

SQL Server Central: [Seven Monitoring Scripts](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administering/sevenmonitoringscripts/1024/)

- Failed jobs report
- Free space by drive
- Disabled jobs
- Running jobs
- Server role members
- Last backup date
- SQL Log

And last, but not least this resource: [SQL Server Programming Hacks - 100+ List](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/SQL_Server_Programming_Hacks_-_100%2B_List)

Answer (score 13):

[Joe Celko's SQL Puzzles and Answers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123735963)

[The Art of SQL (slight Oracle bias)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008945)

Answer (score 12):

[Sql Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596009762/#top) has a variety of interesting example, though some will undoubtedly be unsupported by your RDBMS of choice. O'Reilly also has a [T-SQL Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565927568/#top), but I've never personally read it.

Answer (score 7):

directly from MS Script Repository: SQL Server 2005:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/scripts/sql/sql2005/default.mspx?mfr=true

Nigel's very usefull stuff:
http://www.nigelrivett.net/#TransactSQL

Answer (score 4):

Forgive me for the self-advertising, but I have posted a few on my blog (http://progblog.wordpress.com) because I'm rubbish at SQL and it's a good place to store things I know I'll need in the future :-)  If anyone has anything more substantial then please post, I'm as keen as anyone to get hold of something like this!

I would guess that a copy of the "SQL Cookbook" would help too.

Comment: All contributions are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I've had some use of these SQL "hacks" for Oracle a couple of times.

[Concatenate as grouping function](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/code/tips2006/101606.html)

[In query data generation for joining purposes](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_test_data_date_generation_sql.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another link for SQL Server: best practices - dozens of script examples

[**http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/**](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/)

Answer (score 2):

[Check Out SQLCAT.com (MS SQL BEST PRACTICES TEAM)](http://www.sqlcat.com)

Answer (score 2):

Riffing off the Celko answer:  [SQL For Smarties](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123693799).  This has great in depth chapters that will augment the SQL Puzzles book.  Also there is another Celko book I just learned of named 
[Joe Celko's Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558609202).